# IsRowVersion can only be configured for Byte array properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I recently upgraded from EntityFramework 5 to 6 via the NuGet updater. Everything seemed to go well and I built and executed my application. When I tried to retrieve the first entity from the database, I received this error:

> The property 'UpdatedDate' is not a Byte array. IsRowVersion can only
>   be configured for Byte array properties.

Here is the piece of code it is referring to:

```
[Timestamp]
public virtual DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
```

I tried removing the timestamp attribute, but got the same error regardless. How do I fix this so I can run my application with EF6?

Comment: Your code is wrong.  `ROWVERSION` /`TIMESTAMP` is a byte array and has nothing to do with time.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Comment: Exactly what SLaks said. The name `Timestamp` is **very** misleading for this. Unfortunately it is carried on to EntityFramework...

Comment: I don't understand. The table column is a datetime and there is a Timestamp attribute on the model property. Even if that is wrong, why do I get the same error message when I remove the timestamp attribute?

Comment: Are you sure that you have properly cleaned and rebuilt your code after removing the `Timestamp` attribute? And you don't call manually `IsRowVersion()` in your model configuration? And the type of the column is datatime in the database and you are only using code first?

Comment: Turns out I had a timestamp attribute on another class. The error messages must have been so similar I didn't recognize the reference to the second class. Thanks nemesv.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Attributes in EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx)

If you use `[TimeStamp]` attribute, then the property should be byte[]
This is then mapped to Rowversion in SQL server

If you want some other field type as a concurrency field.
The use the attribute `[ConcurrencyCheck]`

Comment: Or in Fluent API: modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.UpdatedDate).IsConcurrencyToken();